# What kind of pest leaves long, hard, stuck-to-the-tiles droppings like these?

Tags: identification, pests

I have a 3*6 meter construction in my backyard, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQSY4.jpg). No clue what the English name for such constructions is. The sides are fully closed aluminum panelling, and I keep the glass sliding doors closed too. The bottom aluminum panel for the side is dug into the ground, and the tiles are grouted into place. The roof and sliding doors are watertight, so I don't expect anything to be able to crawl in.

The only things I store underneath it are a treadmill and a single stack of two outdoor wooden chairs + coffee table. There aren't any 'hiding spots', and I have by now unstacked and restacked the chairs and table several times to triple-check that nothing is hiding between them. Same for the treadmill, I have even screwed off some of the covers checking for critters and found nothing. As I use it every evening, I would even expect that any critter hiding in it would either be ground up (and I would've smelled something) or have come running out of it by now. I have never found any critters.

As for the rest of the backyard, it is all covered in the same tiles and some small strips of gravel near the fences for water drainage. No garden pots out at the moment, as it's winter in The Netherlands at the moment (they're empty, cleaned, and stored in the shed). So not a critter/pest-friendly environment at all, I would think.

Yet, pretty much every morning, I wake up to some new animal droppings on the tiles underneath my construction. I have never found any in the rest of the backyard. These droppings are hard, and stuck to the tiles to the point that you can't just get rid of them with a broom, I really need to get out a 'poop knife' to scrape these things of the tiles. It's getting annoying. I've put pictures of the droppings below, the tile they're on is 60x60cm (for scale). I'm wondering if anyone knows what kind of animal could be leaving these, and how to find/get rid of it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm going with caterpillar.

Comment: @YosefBaskin You need to be more specific. These aren't frass from any butterfly or moth - frass from those insects are kind of granular and not sticky. There are other genera that have larvae that could be considered "caterpillars", though. If you have one of those in mind, please add it as a comment.

Comment: Could there be insects living in the ceiling joints? If this is excrement, it's as likely to have dropped from above than from something living on the tiles. Also - do you find these droppings on the furniture or treadmill?

Comment: @Jurp I haven't found these on the treadmill or furniture yet, now that you mention it... only on the tiles. The way the roof is built, I don't think anything can be living in the ceiling and dropping these, there is something like a caulked seal all around (that looks undamaged everywhere) between the aluminum and the rooftop plates, the dark line in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKU6s.png. But if anyone knows any insect that will definitely leave such droppings, I'm willing to be proven wrong and to go on an insect hunt!

Comment: Do you have spiders around there? Also, do you place bananas around?

Comment: @Jayparth No bananas, plenty of spiders and webs to get rid of in autumn but not now, in winter.

Comment: That poop seems somehow from spiders. Somewhere around the room you have too many spiders. And when they eat something very fibrous, other than their normal protein based diet they poop that way.

Comment: @Jayparth I doubt it's spiders. These droppings are about twice as long as the biggest spider I ever cleared from under there, and such a spider would be very visible. I checked and found absolutely no spiders, not even the usual tiny ones... I would also seriously doubt there is anything 'fibrous' to eat for those spiders, unless they're gnawing on the wood of the chairs/table (of which I found no evidence). There really isn't *any* plant-like fibrous material available for them.

Comment: Then, my last assumption is that it's cockroach poop from your description. Lookout here: https://www.solutionsstores.com/how-to-identify-pest-by-droppings                 also, look for cockroach droppings images on web and revert if you find cues.

Comment: @Jayparth thanks, but the poop in that image looks very little like these droppings. The description also doesn't match (largest being described as a grain of rice, mine are at least several grains of rice long). Besides that, googling a bit as to the conditions roaches need to survive, I doubt any roaches would be surviving under there in a Dutch winter. According to several exterminators, they need a hot, humid and dark place, while over here it's cold and light (except for between the furniture but I'd have expected to encounter them then when checking for spiders, which I did not).

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Jayparth made 3 comments not about a sofa, too.  Anyway, I took the microclimate thing to be suggesting there is a source of food, shelter, or something else pests desire nearby, even if it is not large enough to be obvious.  Under a sofa (if you had one!) would be an example of where pests could find desirable circumstances.

Comment: Slugs or Snails.